# Submit Fails in cakephp requested address not found, since original url had 2 params

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4, reset-password

I am currently doing a reset password of which is sending the following link to a user in an email

```
 http://localhost/realestateagencyadministration/users/reset/859be257b603ce278c42dca470be642a/48/
```

Then the user goes to the form and the controller does the following

```
public function reset($resetkey = null, $id = null) {

        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }

        $result =$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $id, 'User.resetKey' => "'" . $resetkey . "'")));

        if ($result) {
            $message = __('<b>Please check your reset link</b>');
            $this->Session->setFlash($message);
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->User->save()) {
                $message = __('Your password has been reset');
                $this->Session->setFlash($message);
            } else {
                $message = __('Something has gone wrong. Please try later or <b>sign up again</b>');
                $this->Session->setFlash($message);
            }
        } 
        else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->findByIdAndResetkey( $id,  $resetkey );
            $log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
            debug($log);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I submit it gives an error like so

> Error: The requested address
>   '/realestateagencyadministration/users/reset/48' was not found on this
>   server.

How should I handle this?

Comment: What happens when you access only users reset page without `id` and `resetKey`? Do you still get not found?

Comment: @skywalker when passing no params I get Cannot redeclare UsersController::reset()

Comment: That means you have two methods named reset??

Comment: @skywalker sorry I was testing code there I commented it out and it brought up the same error Error: The requested address '/realestateagencyadministration/users/reset/' was not found on this server. It only works when I pass the parameters.

Comment: Are you sure the user with id 48 exists? If the users is not exist, it will throw NotFoundException.

Comment: @FazalRasel The user does exist since it works until I actually submit then for some reason it changes the link and fails.

Comment: You have `localhost` in your link, are you not using virtual host for this project?

Comment: @skywalker I don't even know what virtual host is. I am using a wamp server setup.

Comment: Is this not found error from cakephp or from apache? And is your debug level set to 2?

Comment: @skywalker yes debug is 2 and the error is given when I submit while in my cakephp project. Thats all I see.

Comment: Ok, so how do you get to this page? You are doing subit from some other action?

Comment: @skywalker as I said in the question the user receives an email. Which I am receiving and then clicks the link. Then load a page with an input for password. Which then after inputted and submitted will update password, and set resetkey to empty but I am currently not doing that yet.

Comment: You said _when I submit_, if you are sending it to mail, it should be something like: `http://somesite.com/users/reset/key/id` or on your localhost: `http://localhost/realestateagencyadministration/users/reset/key/id` is that your case? Are you accessing it with the outside link or link within application?

Comment: @skywalker this is the link I use from the email http://localhost/realestateagencyadministration/users/reset/key/id. The page loads I type the new password then submit after submitting it gives me that error.

Comment: I think you can't send without both params, try rearranging your params, so the id is first and pass it in both times, when you submit and to email.

Comment: @skywalker I noticed it won't work without both params, I have sent the id first like you said. but still am unsure how I should save. As it still fails.

Comment: I wonder how the url changed after submitting form? Do you edit your routes.php? And i can see, you are calling save without any data. Do you define anything on your beforeSave() or beforeFilter()?

Comment: Can you show that form? And try using named params if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: @skywalker I have posted the answer that I have found to work for me. give your comments and if possible a better answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I have found be it correct or not and if anyone has suggestions on how it should be altered do comment.

I took skywalker's suggestion and switched around the params so that id is first.

> public function reset($id = null,$resetkey = null) {

and changed my save code

```
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {                    
        $data = $this->User->findById($id);
        $data['User']['password'] = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
        $data['User']['resetkey'] = '';
        if ($this->User->save($data)) {
            $message = __('Your password has been changed, try logging in with your new password.');
            $this->Session->setFlash($message);
        } else {
            $message = __('Something has gone wrong. Please try again later.');
            $this->Session->setFlash($message);
        }
    }
```

I know it isn't clean and if anyone knows a better way it would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: This won't work if you are hashing password, which you should, do you have `beforeSave()` to do that?

Comment: @skywalker actually this works because of the very fact that I do have before save.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[1] Remove trailing slash (/):

```
http://localhost/realestateagencyadministration
    /users/reset/859be257b603ce278c42dca470be642a/48
```

[2] If still no success, add router statement (app/Config/routes.php),  :

```
Router::connect('/users/reset/:resetkey/:id',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset'),
    array('pass' => array('resetkey', 'id'))); // <-- must be in action argument order
```